# How do I determine why ghc is looking for a particular type class instance?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

When conditional type class instances run deep, it can be difficult to figure out why ghc is complaining about a missing type class instance. For instance:

```
class MyClass1 c
class MyClass2 c
class MyClass3 c

data MyType1 a
data MyType2 a

instance MyClass1 a => MyClass2 (MyType1 a)
instance MyClass2 a => MyClass3 (MyType2 a)

foo :: (MyClass3 c) => c
foo = undefined

bar :: MyType2 (MyType1 Int)
bar = foo
```

GHC gives the following error:

```
Example.hs:149:7-9: error:
    • No instance for (MyClass1 Int) arising from a use of ‘foo’
    • In the expression: foo
      In an equation for ‘bar’: bar = foo
    |
149 | bar = foo
    |       ^^^
```

Supposing I only wrote the definitions for `foo` and `bar`, and everything else was imported code which I did not write, I may be very confused as to why ghc is attempting to find a `MyClass1` instance for `Int`. This might even be the first time I've ever heard of the `MyClass1` class, if so far I've been relying on imported instances. It would be nice if ghc could give me a "stack trace" of the type class instance chain, e.g.

```
Sought (MyClass2 (MyType1 Int)) to satisfy (MyClass3 (MyType2 (MyType1 Int))) from conditional type class instance OtherModule.hs:37:1-18
Sought (MyClass1 Int) to satisfy (MyClass2 (MyType1 Int)) from conditional type class instance OtherModule.hs:36:1-18
```

Does ghc have a command line option for this? If not, how do I debug this?

Keep in mind that my real problem is much more complicated than this simple example. e.g.

```
Search.hs:110:31-36: error:
    • Could not deduce (Ord
                          (Vars (DedupingMap (Rep (Index gc)) (IndexedProblem ac))))
        arising from a use of ‘search’
      from the context: (PP gc (IndexedProblem ac),
                         Show (Vars (DedupingMap (Rep (Index gc)) (IndexedProblem ac))),
                         Foldable f, MonadNotify m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   searchIndexedReplicaProblem :: forall gc ac (f :: * -> *) (m :: *
                                                                                   -> *).
                                                  (PP gc (IndexedProblem ac),
                                                   Show
                                                     (Vars
                                                        (DedupingMap
                                                           (Rep (Index gc)) (IndexedProblem ac))),
                                                   Foldable f, MonadNotify m) =>
                                                  f (Index
                                                       (Clzs
                                                          (PartitionedProblem
                                                             gc (IndexedProblem ac))))
                                                  -> m (Maybe
                                                          (Vars
                                                             (PartitionedProblem
                                                                gc (IndexedProblem ac))))
        at Search.hs:(103,1)-(109,131)
    • In the expression: search
      In an equation for ‘searchIndexedReplicaProblem’:
          searchIndexedReplicaProblem = search
    |
110 | searchIndexedReplicaProblem = search
    |                               ^^^^^^
```

There are five coverage conditions for PP, and I'm using type families and undecidable instances, so it's extremely not obvious why ghc is giving me its error. What tools can I use to track down the problem?

Comment: Possibly related: [Reifying Instance Resolution](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/sloan/reifying-instance-resolution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `-ddump-cs-trace` option, though it is aimed to help GHC devs when debugging constrains solving code, but it could be useful for you too. Here is the output for your example:

```
Step 1[l:2,d:0] Kept as inert:
    [G] $dMyClass3_a1rt {0}:: MyClass3 c_a1rs[sk:2]
Step 2[l:2,d:0] Dict equal (keep):
    [WD] $dMyClass3_a1rv {0}:: MyClass3 c_a1rs[sk:2]
Constraint solver steps = 2
Step 1[l:1,d:0] Top react: Dict/Top (solved wanted):
    [WD] $dMyClass3_a2uc {0}:: MyClass3 (MyType2 (MyType1 Int))
Step 2[l:1,d:1] Top react: Dict/Top (solved wanted):
    [WD] $dMyClass2_a2up {1}:: MyClass2 (MyType1 Int)
Step 3[l:1,d:2] Kept as inert:
    [WD] $dMyClass1_a2uq {2}:: MyClass1 Int
Step 4[l:2,d:0] Kept as inert:
    [G] $dMyClass3_a1rB {0}:: MyClass3 c_a1rz[sk:2]
Step 5[l:2,d:0] Wanted CallStack IP:
    [WD] $dIP_a2u8 {0}:: ?callStack::GHC.Stack.Types.CallStack
Step 6[l:2,d:0] Kept as inert:
    [WD] $dIP_a2uA {0}:: ?callStack::GHC.Stack.Types.CallStack
Step 7[l:2,d:0] Kept as inert:
    [G] $dMyClass2_a2uh {0}:: MyClass2 a_a2ug[ssk:2]
Step 8[l:2,d:0] Kept as inert:
    [G] $dMyClass1_a2ul {0}:: MyClass1 a_a2uk[ssk:2]
Constraint solver steps = 8
```

It is not easy to extract useful information from this dump, but AFAIK it is the only available option right now. Few related tickets: [13443](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13443), [15044](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15044)

ADDED:
I'll try to explain a bit what the dump means. I'm not actually familiar with GHC internals, so it is just my (probably wrong) understanding.

The relevant bit is the next:

```
Step 1[l:1,d:0] Top react: Dict/Top (solved wanted):
    [WD] $dMyClass3_a2uc {0}:: MyClass3 (MyType2 (MyType1 Int))
Step 2[l:1,d:1] Top react: Dict/Top (solved wanted):
    [WD] $dMyClass2_a2up {1}:: MyClass2 (MyType1 Int)
Step 3[l:1,d:2] Kept as inert:
    [WD] $dMyClass1_a2uq {2}:: MyClass1 Int
```

Here `d` stands for "depth", `WD` is "wanted derived" constraint. So we have something like a stack trace of wanted constraints: initially we wanted `MyClass3 (MyType2 (MyType1 Int))`, then we found the `MyClass3` instance for `MyType2`, and now we want `MyClass2 (MyType1 Int)` to satisfy it. Then we found the `MyClass2` instance for `MyType1`, now we want `MyClass1 Int` to satisfy it. I know, the explanation is vague, but that is all I have for you, sorry.

Comment: For users new to this kind of output (like me!), could you write your interpretation of what each of these lines means?

Comment: @DanielWagner I updated the answer. Unfortunately I can't describe the dump line by line, because I simply don't know enough.